# In C++, how to iterate array in reverse using for_each?

Tags: c++11, stl, stdarray

In C++11, using lambda/for_each, how do we iterate an array from end?

I tried the following, but both result in infinite loop:

```
for_each (end(A), begin(A), [](int i) {
   ....
});

for_each (A.rend(), A.rbegin(), [](int i) {
    ...
});
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: You inverted rend and rbegin.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You missed this ?

Flip your `rbegin` & `rend`

```
for_each (A.rbegin(), A.rend(), [](int i) {
    ...
});
```

Increasing reverse iterator moves them towards the beginning of the container

Answer (score 7):

`std::for_each( A.rbegin(), A.rend(), [](int i) { /*code*/ } );` is the simple solution.

I instead have written `backwards` which takes a sequence, extracts the `begin` and `end` iterator from it using the free `begin` and `end` functions (with `std::begin` and `std::end` `using` declarations nearby -- full ADL), creates reverse iterators around them, then returns a sequence with those two reverse iterators.

It is sort of neat, because you get this syntax:

```
for( int i : backwards(A) ) {
  // code
}
```

which I find easier to read than `std::for_each` or manual `for` loops.

But I am a bit nuts.

Here is a minimal `backwards`.  A full on solution handles adl and a few corner cases better.

```
template<class It, class C>
struct range_for_t{
  It b,e;
  C c; // for lifetime
  It begin()const{return b;}
  It end()const{return e;}
}
template<class It, class C>
range_for_t<It,C> range_for(It b,It e,C&& c){
  return {std::move(b),std::move(e),std::forward<C>(c)};
}

template<class It>
range_for_t<It,int> range_for(It b,It e){
  return {std::move(b),std::move(e)};
}
```

A simple range for range for only.  Can be augmented with perfect forwarding.

Passing `C` as the container that may need lifetime extending. If passed as rvalue, copy is made, otherwise just reference.  It is otherwise not used.

Next part is easy:

```
template<class It>
auto reverse_it(It it){
  return std::reverse_iterator<It>(std::move(it));
} 
template<class C>
auto backwards(C&&c){
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto b=begin(c), e=end(c);
  return range_for(
    reverse_it(e),reverse_it(b),
    std::forward<C>(c)
  );
}
```

That is untested but should work.

One important test is ensuring it works when you feed an rvalue vec like:

```
 for(auto x:backwards(make_vec()))
```

works -- that is what the mess around storing `C` is about.  It also assumes that moved container iterators have iterators who behave nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Since C++20, there is a convenient adaptor for this:

```
#include <ranges>

...

for (auto& element: container | std::views::reverse)
```

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> container {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    for (const auto& elem: container | std::views::reverse )
    {
        std::cout << elem << ' ';
    }
}

// Prints 5 4 3 2 1
```

Try it here:
https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e320e5eec431cc87

Answer (score 1):

Boost offers a feature named [reversed](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/reversed.html), that can be used with [C++ 11 range based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) as describes Yakk in his answer:

```
for(int i : reverse(A))
{
  // code
}
```

or

```
for(int i : A | reversed)
{
  // code
}
```